# What do you call a relation that is transitive and reflexive

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs

Does anyone know an "official" name for a relation that is transitive and reflexive, but not necessarily anti-symmetric?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), "a preorder is reflexive and transitive".